# Android: storing files in Downloads

Tags: android, mediastore, storage-access-framework

With Android 10 and scoped storage it's not possible to use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` anymore.
There are multiple other options, including MediaStore and Storage Access Framework.
Our email app would like to only append new files to Downloads collection. We must pre-process them locally so we can't use DownloadManager.

[MediaStorage guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#java) mentions

> Note: Although it's possible to store general-purpose files in either the Documents/ folder or the Download/ folder—including non-media files—it's better to use the Storage Access Framework (SAF) for these use cases.

But from what I understand from [Storage Access Framework guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) we would have to prompt user each time when they want to download a file and it seems unnecessary.

What is the common practice for appending files to Downloads?

Comment: For Android 10 devices just request legacy external storage in manifest and you are done. Then it acts as before.

Comment: `we would have to prompt user each time when they want to download the file and it seems unnecessary.` The file? Or a file? No. Let the user once select a directory then you can create as many files in it as you want.

Comment: A file, thanks.
And if they select wrong directory, will they find it ever later?
We went with MediaStorage for now and it's Downloads collection.

Comment: blackapps is wrong and as usual, provides no solutions.  Android 10 is a total mess in terms of access and 11 tries to rectify that somewhat but things just get worse. You will only able to read/write files located in your app "file space". Any special permissions required outside this eg backup apps etc will require google approval. My app for instance is already broken as it tries to create music playlists or read/write mp3 tags

Comment: @charlag have you ever figure out the solution for this? I'm running in the same issue atm.

Comment: We use `ContentResolver` since Q and `Environment` on old versions
see
https://github.com/tutao/tutanota/blob/0c9270caf3b2595dff230b3b5ab5158ee0495764/app-android/app/src/main/java/de/tutao/tutanota/AndroidFileFacade.kt#L135-L184

Answer (score 4):

here is an exemple to write à file in download folder :

```
   OutputStream out;

   ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();

   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, localPath);
   contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf");
   contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
   Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues);
   out = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri);
```

Comment: I did something similar but you do not need `RELATIVE_PATH`, it's meant only for subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

You can save downloaded files to `Download` folder, regardless of the API levels:

```java
FileDescription file = new FileDescription(fileName, subFolder, mimeType);
Uri fileUri = DocumentFileCompat.createDownloadWithMediaStoreFallback(context, file);
```

Open output stream with `fileUri` and write data into it.

Anyway, `DocumentFileCompat` is only available in [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage).

Comment: Thanks for the link but probably the best would be to find out what SimpleStorage does and explain it here.